# Send binary data via WCF: binary vs MTOM encoding

Tags: wcf, encoding, binding, binary, mtom

I have limited knowledge in WCF as well as sending binary data via WCF, so this question may be somewhat rudimental.

I would like to know the difference between sending data with `BinaryMessageEncodingBindingElement` and `MtomMessageEncodingBindingElement`. It is still not clear to me when to use which approach after reading this page from MSDN on [Large Data and Streaming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733742.aspx).

Also, a small question: are a message with attachments and an MTOM message the same thing?

Comment: It is mostly about interoperability. Do you want to have interoperable service? Use Mtom. Do  you want to call the service only from WCF client? Use binary message encoding.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

MTOM is a standard that uses multi-part mime-encoded messages to send portions of the message that are large and would be too expensive to base64 encode as pure binary. The SOAP message itself is sent as the initial part of the message and contains references to the binary parts which a web service software stack like WCF can then pull back together to create a single representation of the message.

Binary encoding is entirely proprietary to WCF and really doesn't just have to do with large messages. It presents a binary representation of the XML Infoset which is far more compact across the wire and faster to parse than text based formats. If you happen to be sending large binary chunks of data then it just fits right in with the other bytes that are being sent.

Streaming can be done used with any message format. That's more about when the data is written across the network vs. being buffered entirely in memoery before being presented to the network transport. Smaller messages make more sense to buffer up before sending and larger messages, especially those containing large binary chunks or streams, necessitate being streamed or will exhaust memory resources.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! So, is MTOM just a SOAP message with attachments, similar to attachments in SMTP messages?

Comment: @Drew Marsh , But how can he include a binary data inside it  ( withougt decode it to base 64) and then send it over http ?

Comment: Do you have any code sample of how to attach a binary file as MTOM in WCF?