# Configure asp.net to allow POST with binary

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, iis, configuration

I have a new asp.net (4.0) project and I am trying to make a binary POST request from a flash script. From fiddler I can see the the header is well formed but the request results in a 500 message. Is there anything I need to add/remove anything from a standard web.config to get this working?

Comment: What protocol are you using? HTTP doesn't permit arbitrary binary without some encoding.

Comment: `HTTP` = "*Hypertext* Transfer Protocol"

Comment: Do you have any control over the flash script of your project?

Comment: This may help:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6846238/send-binary-data-via-wcf-binary-vs-mtom-encoding

Comment: Have you checked to make sure the file being uploaded doesn't exceed the maxRequestLenght web config value (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641.aspx) or the IIS max vaue (http://www.webtrenches.com/post.cfm/iis7-file-upload-size-limits)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base-64 encode the binary data.  This is the typical way to transmit binary data via text.

Answer (score 0):

The Windows application log should have the detailed exception. I would look there first. If that doesn't illuminate the problem, then a few things come to mind.

Set `maxRequestLength` in your web.config to a number that is definitely larger than the request you are making. (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641.aspx).

Also, check the MIME type of the request.