# Is WCF text and mtom encoding also binary encoding?

Tags: wcf, serialization

I need help understanding message encoding in WCF. As I understand it, messages are encoded in Binary, Text or Mtom -- there may be others. What confuses me is that once you get to the bottom of the protocol stack, EVERYTHING is in binary. So how come binary is an encoding? Do they mean that when it's in text, it first creates a text representation of the object in memory and then serializes that text into binary and sends it across the wire? And if the encoding is binary, then the in-memory objects being passed across the wire, just go from their native binary representation straight to network packets (passing through transport protocols packets of course). Can someone tell me if I'm getting this right?

Comment: start here for help understanding MTOM vs Binary:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6846238/send-binary-data-via-wcf-binary-vs-mtom-encoding